# My iPad Air Wi-Fi (A1474) won't restart after getting a new system update

Tags: ipad, software-update, restart

After I updated my iPad Air Wi-Fi (A1474), I couldn't get it to turn on again.

What could have possibly gone wrong and how do I rectify?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Please check if you can see anything displayed on the screen. Try keeping it plugged into power for some time and check again.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your device in recovery mode, you'll need a lightning cable and iTunes
https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201263